# bootstrap datatable with php code does not work

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use data table to sort and search in the `database` with `bootstrap 4` but it does not work like it is not sorting , pagination or searching the data. I don't know why it's not working. Here's my code:

```
    <link href="css/addons/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <div class="table-responsive">
       <table id="datas" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">

         <thead style="color:black;" >
           <th>id</th>
           <th>Product</th>
           <th>Price</th>
           <th>Weight</th>
           <th>Image</th>
           <th>Type</th>
           <th>Type 2</th>
         </thead>    

    <?php

    $get = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products;");

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {
      $id=$row['product_id'];
      $name=$row['product_name'];

      $type2=$row['product_type'];
      $weight=$row['weight'];
      $price=$row['product_price'];

      $type=$row['type'];
      $img=$row['img'];    

      $get1 = mysqli_query($conn," SELECT * FROM money WHERE name='$type' ");

      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get1)) {
        $p=$row['price'];  
        $newprice = $p*$weight;    
      }   

?>
        <tbody>
        <td><?php echo $id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
        <td>$<?php echo $newprice;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $weight;?> g</td>
        <td>
          <img  src="<?php echo $img; ?>" style="height:5rem;width:5rem;border-radius:10px;">
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $type;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $type2;?></td>

        </tbody>

        <?php
        }
        ?>  


          </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/addons/datatables.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#datas').DataTable();
      });
    </script>
```

it been 4 days i am trying to fix this i tried bootstrap 3 as well but still same result

dose any body know what is the problem ? is there is something i am missing ? 
here is picture of how the data table looks like  [image: pic]
the data table is created but dose not work.

[image: console errors]

Comment: t should sort by default, but you can try this $('#example').dataTable( {
  "ordering": true
} );

Comment: You should probably not create a new `tbody` around every single row …?

Comment: @Emilia, Datatable is applied to it. You should have some errors in the console for missing fonts. Please check

Comment: 04FS is probably right, it repeats the body element, body element should there only be once.

Comment: i move out the tbody from the while code it ruined the whole design

Comment: @AlokMali yes it got a lot of errors i updated the post with errors picture

Comment: @Emilia, You don't have .woff and .ttf files. That's why it is not showing the sorting icons. Please download the files and place them on appropriate location.

Comment: You can find the location where to place those files, by clicking on` Ubuntu-Bold.ttf:1`.

Comment: After you move the `<tbody>` tags out of the loop you need to replace them with `<tr>` tags.

Comment: @AlokMali i tried to include online and with css but still got the same error

Comment: @mark_b  i did that too but still does not work

Comment: @Emilia, try after adding this CSS - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @AlokMali still no result 
maybe it is the templates problem this is my second one 
i think im going to change it again hope it will work

Comment: @Emilia, You should try after download and place `.woff` and `.ttf` files.

Comment: @AlokMali a added all the fonts now i do not have the font errors but still dose not work but i still have another error says 

Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Answer (score -1):

Because you have to put `<tbody>` outside of your while loop and you also forgot to add table-raw tag `<tr>`, I have updated your code

```
<tbody>
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get1)) {
$p=$row['price'];  
$newprice = $p*$weight;

}
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $id;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
    <td>$<?php echo $newprice;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $weight;?> g</td>
    <td>
      <img  src="<?php echo $img; ?>" style="height:5rem;width:5rem;border-radius:10px;">
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $type;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $type2;?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>  
</tbody>
```

Answer (score -1):

You used the same variables that's why maybe the result is overlapped. Try to use two different variables like $row and $row1.

Answer (score -1):

you put `<tbody>` in while loop and php echo it.
and error in pic3 its for fonts.check src and link to fonts
and finally your code is here

```
<link href="css/addons/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="datas" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">

        <thead style="color:black;" >
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Type 2</th>
        </thead>

        <?php

        $get = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products;");
?>
        <tbody>
<?php
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {
            $id=$row['product_id'];
            $name=$row['product_name'];

            $type2=$row['product_type'];
            $weight=$row['weight'];
            $price=$row['product_price'];

            $type=$row['type'];
            $img=$row['img'];

            $get1 = mysqli_query($conn," SELECT * FROM money WHERE name='$type' ");

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get1)):
                $p=$row['price'];
                $newprice = $p*$weight;
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
            <td>$<?php echo $newprice;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $weight;?> g</td>
            <td>
                <img  src="<?php echo $img; ?>" style="height:5rem;width:5rem;border-radius:10px;">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $type;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $type2;?></td>

            </tbody>

            <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>


    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/addons/datatables.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#datas').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
```